# Including (public domain?) lyrics of a song in my screenplay?

Tags: copyright, screenwriting

In my screenplay, the lyrics of "Shenandoah", a traditional American folk song, are heard once. May I publish a few lines with the words?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean "[Shenandoah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh_Shenandoah)", that one seems safe enough from a legal
standpoint, being quite old and a folk song with no clear author; but be
careful with more recent works. A work can be in the public domain
federally but still be under copyright in some states or encumbered in
other ways. [Nina Paley was famously bitten by this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sita_Sings_the_Blues#Copyright_problems) when she made *Sita
Sings the Blues*. And, of course, international copyrights might apply
to anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're pretty safe with that one. Some sort of acknowledgements page is usually good form, or whatever the equivalent is in scriptwriting.